# lxd init: bind: address already in use

Tags: lxc, lxd

I have problem with bind problem with lxd init. The port 8443 is not used by any other application, therefore I think, lxd init tries to bind this port twice.

My lxd version is 3.14 and I am using Gentoo.

Do you have any idea how to solve this please?

```
alpha /var/log # lxd init
Would you like to use LXD clustering? (yes/no) [default=no]: yes
What name should be used to identify this node in the cluster? [default=alpha]: alpha.stty.cz
What IP address or DNS name should be used to reach this node? [default=171.25.220.247]: alpha.stty.cz
Are you joining an existing cluster? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Setup password authentication on the cluster? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Trust password for new clients: 
Again: 
Do you want to configure a new local storage pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Name of the storage backend to use (btrfs, dir, lvm) [default=btrfs]: 
Would you like to create a new btrfs subvolume under /var/lib/lxd? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Do you want to configure a new remote storage pool? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like to connect to a MAAS server? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like to configure LXD to use an existing bridge or host interface? (yes/no) [default=no]: yes
Name of the existing bridge or host interface: ovs-br0
Would you like stale cached images to be updated automatically? (yes/no) [default=yes] 
Would you like a YAML "lxd init" preseed to be printed? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Error: Failed to update server configuration: cannot listen on https socket: listen tcp 171.25.220.247:8443: bind: address already in use
```

The output of `sudo netstat -pna | grep 8443` is

```
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28443    7135/konsole
```

The issue is also published on Github. (https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/7560)

Comment: _The port 8443 is not used by any other application, therefore I think_. Can you verify that for other users with the output of: `sudo netstat -pna | grep 8443`? Feel free to update your question with it. That being said, if you find that it really isn't in use then it is likely trying to bind the port twice. Could you share the config?

Comment: Done. Which configuration should I share?

Comment: You may want to consider updating to at least lxd-3.19 or later, as this issue may have been a bug: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/6682.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you will need to update your version of lxd to 3.19 or higher; searching through bugs and issues brought me to this thread:

github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/6682

`netstat` will show not any process listening on 8443 and it sounds like there is no configuration that might be pear-shaped. It simply looks to be a bug that you've caught in an older version of lxd.